# Sign up on freenom

Tags: domain

## hi, how do i sign up for [freenom?](https://my.freenom.com/sociallogin.php)

I am a `html` dev and was wondering how to make a account for freenom. Currently i cannot find any singup page, or url. When looking around, I found this [support post](https://www.freenom.com/en/support.html#m) but it did not help.

---

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Complete the "check availability" option from the home page.
- Enter both the required domain name AND the extension. For instance, don't just enter `brycenweeks` but, say, `brycenweeks.ml`
- Assuming this domain is available, click "checkout" and complete the process.

Comment: Thank you so much! I could not figure this out! Thank you!